# how to force to Reinstall APK

Tags: android, installation

I want to export a new version of my APPLICATION, and i want to force the user to uninstall and reinstall the app for the new version (for different reasons). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the signature of your app, will do the trick. What happens is that the system will warn the user when installing the new app that this app was found but with a different signature. The user has to uninstall the current app before the new app can be installed.

A more direct way than this does not exist. And there is a chance that many users won't understand why the app does not install. You should try to make your app so that this won't be necessary. Uninstalling the current app will also mean that the users loses it's data.

Another option is to change the package name in the manifest file, but this will mean the user loses all it's app data. Because the app will be installed as totally new app.

It's bad....

Rolf

Comment: how can i change the signature?

Comment: Just add a new signature,
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature / key of your apk. I have read the this forces a full uninstall on the devices

[image]

Screenshot from eclipse.

Comment: not work. in eclipse i increment the apk code in androidManifest.xml, then: File -> export: and create a new key and create a new signature. And nothing, when install, android says to replace app

Comment: Really?? Not that I ever tried, but wouldn't this install a new app with the same name and icon and all. Can you provide a link where you found this info?

Comment: I think you have to create a new key using the assistent in eclipse. But I never try it.